# How to count a sum of numbers multiple 2, 3, 5 and 7?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

When I try to count a sum of multiple numbers I got not correct data. Instead of big results, programm shows little numbers like: SUMM OF 2 = 100. It can't be, because the last number multiple 2 is 98.

```
    public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        multipleNums();
    }

    static void multipleNums(){
        int i = 0;
        int multTwo = 0;
        int multThree = 0;
        int multFive = 0;
        int multSeven = 0;

        int summTwo = 0;
        int summThree = 0;
        int summFive = 0;
        int summSeven = 0;

        for(i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
        if(i == 0){    
            System.out.println("0 multiple 0");
        }else if(i%2 == 0){
            System.out.println(i + " multiple 2");
            summTwo = i + multTwo;

        }else if(i%3 == 0){
            System.out.println(i + " multiple 3");
            summThree = i + multThree;

        }else if(i%5 == 0){
            System.out.println(i + " multiple 5");
            summFive = i + multFive;

        }else if(i%7 == 0){
            System.out.println(i + " multiple 7");
            summSeven = i + multSeven;
        } else {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("SUMM OF 2 " + summTwo);
        System.out.println("SUMM OF 3 " + summThree);
        System.out.println("SUMM OF 5 " + summFive);
        System.out.println("SUMM OF 7 " + summSeven);
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO the best tool for you to use to fix this is your debugger.

Comment: What do you think the `mult*` variables are for? And what if numbers are divisible by more than one number?

Comment: Not sure what's the purpose of the `mult*` variables (they remain 0), but in order to sum, use summTwo += i, not summTwo = i;

Comment: I need to have results such: 2+4+6+8+10+...+98

Comment: this is some kind of fizzbuzz problem. 
consider when i = 6. it will first check if it is divisible by 2, the condition will turn true, then it will jump to check 7. however it is also divisible by 3 and multThree should also be incremented by 1.  
have a look up this implementation if you are familiar with js arrow syntax. it is simply a set of ternary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your always adding `multTwo`, `multThree` etc. which are `0`. You should change your code to use `sumXY += i`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line
       `summTwo = i + multTwo;`
to
       `summTwo += i ;`
do this for other variables, 3,5,7..